# How can I mount my external linux booter to my mac, so that I don't need to plug in the USB every time I want to boot linux?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, dual-boot

When booting from Mac to Linux(Kali) on my early 2015 Mac air running Big Sur, I need to have the USB plugged in. There are absolutely no problems with booting, I can even disconnect and reconnect the USB with the Kali booter on it, on the restarting booting screen(with it registering and making a satisfying smoke effect when the disk disappears), but I cannot access the booter if the usb is connected. I am fairly certain all the data itself is stored on the computer, and I'm guessing that it's the system/iso(or whatever became of it once all the weird dual boot stuff was done) that is on the USB which I need the USB connected for? For extra context, the USB was erased and set to the Master Boot Record scheme, but later changed to an Apple Partition Map once I used balenaEtcher to write the Kali iso to it.[image: A Screenshot of my Disk Utility on the USB(it does not show on the desktop)]

*A Screenshot of my Disk Utility on the USB(the USB does not show on the desktop)*

How can I attach the (I'm presuming) Kali system/iso to my main internal disk so I can just as easily boot between Mac and Linux as I do now (as long as the USB is connected), but without the hassle of the USB?

EDIT: I have read through other similar posts, but I was having trouble either understanding them, or they didn't seem applicable.

EDIT 2: @David_Anderson and @Tetsujin, Thank you for the questions! It says MS-DOS (FAT12): [image]

*Screenshot of actual content disk of USB*

And for the question on which file it was [here](https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-installer-images), the 64 bit.

Finally, I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1z_a1AJOVk) tutorial to a T, except for the Wi-Fi setup where I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mss2skNvStk) one.

Comment: What format is the actual disk2s2 partition? macOS can't see [or mount] extFS, which tends to be what nix runs on.

Comment: Which file did you download from Kali?